# What is Android Dalvik?

Tags: android

When I connected the Android with meterpreter it shows the operating system as "Android/Dalvik" what does that mean?

Comment: From a google search I found: _Dalvik is a discontinued[1] process virtual machine (VM) in Google's Android operating system that executes applications written for Android._

Comment: But why it is still there in newer version of Android?

Comment: What is "the Android" you speak of and what version is it running?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Android SE

Comment: Whenever I connect any Android operating system through metasploit whether it is Android Gingerbread to Android Oreo all shows the same

Comment: @SAKETupadhyay post in https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments, Dalvik is the original android JIT just in time, java compiler and run time environment. It's what compiled into machine code and ran android applications (apks). It was replaced in android 5.0 with ART.

Meta sploit simply hasn't made changes to address this change, and has left some strings that call it the wrong thing.